# Scheme: high order procedure and recursion

Tags: recursion, dictionary, scheme

I'm using scheme as part of a course I'm taking. I've been told to use high order functions in my homework. However this instruction seems somewhat unclear.

I don't fully understand the idea of a high order procedure. I'm able to do all the questions using recursion but that it's the same thing. Can anyone explain it with an example of a recursive function vs one written with a high order procedure.

As a second question:

Example: try to grab all the odd numbers

I could use `(flatten (map odd ((1 4 5) (4 5 1 4 9))))`, but what if there were nested lists, can I use map on a nested lists like:

`(flatten (map odd ((1 3 (9 5 7))))` ; is there a function for this or a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a higher-order function is to reduce the boilerplate in your code, and to decrease coupling between the looping (technically it's a recursion, but its purpose is looping, so I will refer to it as such) and the actual logic. Here's an example (re grabbing all the odd numbers): a manual loop would look like this:

```
(define (filter-odd lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((odd? (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (filter-odd (cdr lst))))
        (else (filter-odd (cdr lst)))))
```

But notice that you've got the looping and the filtering in one function. This makes it harder to figure out what the function is doing, since these two unrelated operations are coupled together. With higher-level functions, you can do differently:

```
(define (filter pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((pred (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (filter pred (cdr lst))))
        (else (filter pred (cdr lst)))))

(define (filter-odd lst)
  (filter odd? lst))
```

Notice now, how `odd?` is separated from the looping logic, which has now been separated into `filter`? `filter` now takes a function object which decides whether the item is to be kept or not, and callers of `filter` can slot in any function of their choice.

**That is what is meant by a higher-order function: it's a function that takes a function object as a parameter, to customise its operation.**

As mentioned in the original edit of your question, `map` is another higher-order function, but instead of filtering items from a list, it returns a transformation of every item in the original list, where the specific transformation is given by `map`'s caller via a parameter.

---

To answer your actual question about flattening, etc., `(map filter-odd '((1 3 (9 5 7))))` will return a list with a single item, the result of calling `(filter-odd '(1 3 (9 5 7)))`. So no, `map` will not recurse into sublists for you (and neither will `filter`).

But you can flatten the input first (since you're flattening the output anyway), then call `filter-odd` on that directly. I hope that will give you the result you expect.

(I renamed your `odd` to `filter-odd`, since that is less likely to be confused with `odd?` (the predicate).)

---

#### Bonus material

By the way, both `filter` and `map` are specialisations of a much more general higher-order function, called a fold (or more specifically, a right-fold). Folds can express things that cannot be accommodated by either `filter` or `map`, but that somehow involve traversing all the items in a list. Here's an example of a `length` function, expressed as a fold:

```
(define (foldl func init lst)
  (if (null? lst) init
      (foldl func (func (car lst) init) (cdr lst))))

(define (length lst)
  (foldl (lambda (elem count)
           (+ count 1))
         0 lst))
```

The benefit here is that the `length` function does not have to worry about traversing the list: that is handled by the fold. It only needs to worry about what to do at each iteration (which, here, is simply adding 1 to `count`, which starts out as 0).

In this case, the length is the same whether we traverse from the left or the right, and in Scheme, traversing from the left is more space-efficient, so we prefer that. But for implementing `map` and `filter`, a right-fold is necessary (otherwise the elements come out reversed---try substituting the `foldr` with `foldl` in the below functions and you'll see):

```
(define (foldr func init lst)
  (if (null? lst) init
      (func (car lst) (foldr func init (cdr lst)))))

(define (map func lst)
  (foldr (lambda (elem result)
           (cons (func elem) result))
         '() lst))

(define (filter pred lst)
  (foldr (lambda (elem result)
           (if (pred elem)
               (cons elem result)
               result))
         '() lst))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got most of it and I'll give it another read through just to be sure :) Really helped.